# Using a ODE in another ODE with args make the code very very slow

Tags: python, ode

I wrote the following code. It is a `ODE` which has a parameter in it as another ODE.
As we can see `M(m0,z,b,c)` in used in another `ODE` which itself is a `ODE` function. the code is very slow, Could anyone give me a suggestion how to improve it?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def model(m,z,c,b):
    dmdt = ((c**2-m)/(1+z))*(6-9*(m/c**2)+3*b*(m+(m**2)))
    return dmdt


def M(m0,z,c,b):
        m = odeint(model,m0,[0,z], args= (c, b))
        mm=m[-1,0]
        return mm

def model1(H ,z,m0,c,b):
    c = 0.6
    b=0.035
    dHdt = (H/(1+z))*(6-9*(M(m0,z,c,b)/c**2)+3*b*(M(m0,z,c,b)+(M(m0,z,c,b)**2)))
    return dHdt

def model2(H0,z,m0,c,b):
    H = odeint(model1,H0,[0,z], args=(m0,c,b))
    HH=H[-1,0]
    return HH

print(model2(70,1,0.75,0.69,0.035))
```

Comment: It will be slow - on each step of solving the larger model, you'll have to solve the smaller one. Can you solve it analytically perhaps?

Comment: @Grisha No, The free parameters are more than 100,000 numbers.

Comment: If you have one expensive function call, you do not repeat it with the same parameters multiple times, you call it once, store the result in a variable and re-use it where needed. But that is still not the best way to speed up the computation, see answer.

Comment: Also, you should not change the parameters in `model1`, the ones passed by the call to `model2` are invalidated by the hard-coded values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve a coupled system as a coupled system.

```
def model(U,z,c,b):
    M, H = U
    dMdt = ((c**2-M)/(1+z))*(6-9*(M/c**2)+3*b*(M+M**2))
    dHdt =       (H /(1+z))*(6-9*(M/c**2)+3*b*(M+M**2))
    return [dMdt, dHdt]

def solution(H0,z,m0,c,b):
    U = odeint(model,[m0,H0],[0,z], args=(c,b))[-1]
    M, H = U
    return H

print(solution(70,1,0.75,0.69,0.035))
```

which rapidly returns `0.107569653042` while your code with the modifications

```
 def model1(H, z, m0, c, b):
     mm = M(m0,z,c,b)
     dHdt = (H/(1+z))*(6-9*(mm/c**2)+3*b*(mm+(mm)**2)))
     return dHdt
```

returns the similar `0.107569746892` somewhat slower. These 6 digits of coincidence are consistent with the default error tolerances of `1e-6`.

To get results with higher accuracy set the control parameters for the error tolerances `atol, rtol`.

For further reduction in operations do

```
def model(U,z,c,b):
    M, H = U
    factor = (6-9*M/c**2+3*b*(M+M**2))/(1+z)
    return [(c**2-M)*factor, H*factor]
```

If your task is really massive, use a compiled programming language for fast mass number crunching.

Comment: Thank you. I couldnt quite catch this sentence `If your task is really massive, use a compiled programming language for fast mass number crunching.`

Comment: Python is good for rapid proto-typing, in the dark ages one used BASIC for that role. But interpreted languages, even with JIT compilation into byte code, have a large overhead around each computational operation. This overhead is reduced to almost nothing whenever the computation is compiled to machine code. You can even use the same solver if you can handle the FORTRAN interface of the `lsoda,...` package of solvers. Or use the `gsl` solvers in `C`, the comprehensive solver library of `julia`, ...

Comment: Ah, you suggest using FORTRAN.  Thanks. I do it for some other calculations.

Comment: No, you can use these libraries with any other language, you only need to know about the calling conventions, esp. the memory allocation, or use a wrapper if available, such as `scipy.integrate.odeint` which is a python wrapper for `lsoda`. On the other hand, as a test I just applied my code to a 100x100 sample of `(b,c)` pairs and that took 24.6s, so if you do the massive calculations not very often you can stay with python and wait the 5-10min that it takes for 100000 samples.

Comment: I can understand what you say, but I cannot implement them by my own knowledge, I am physicist and just use what I need, but lack of proper knowledge got me stuck in some important issue. I do not use for loop, I use random selection for each parameter and for 1000,000 steps. I think it is huge.